# How to point eglot to project-specific typescript-language-server

Tags: eglot, tree-sitter, typescript

I have set up tree-sitter and typescript-ts-mode.

But if I activate eglot using `M-x eglot` it complains that it can't find the `typescript-language-server` executable – well duh, I didn't install it globally ... :-)

The question is, what's the recommended way to make it realize that the current tsconfig.json actually has a [typescript-eslint-language-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-eslint-language-service) plugin defined and that it should use the locally installed [typescript-language-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-language-server).

Something that goes into .dir-locals.el – ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with typescript (or javascript), but I think generally a language server should be installed globally, and the server should be configured for the project. I guess the  `typescript-language-server` will automatically determine the project by looking for the tsconfig.json, and use its configuration (just guessing, if not, then find out how to configure it).

Eglot uses the emacs built-in 'project.el' for determining the project root. So if you are already using some supported VC (see `vc-handled-backends`) or [EDE](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/ede.html) this part will be fine. Otherwise, you should configure eglot to find the right project root by adding `tsconfig.json` to the `project-vc-extra-root-markers`:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'project-vc-extra-root-markers "tsconfig.json")
```

Finally, Emacs uses `typescript-language-server` by default for js-mode, js-ts-mode, tsx-ts-mode, typescript-ts-mode and typescript-mode (see `eglot-server-programs`), so that you can just start eglot without further configuration.